# All characters that may be bullet points (e.g. "*") or "dash" points

Tags: regex, unicode, utf-8, character

This question is a simple point (pardon the pun):

What are all the characters that may, when starting a paragraph, be reasonably interpreted as indicating (in the Anglo-saxon demographic) that the paragraph was meant to be a bullet point or a "dash" point.

Here are the ones I would expect, so far:

#### Bullets

- Asterisk: "*",
- HTML entity `&#8266;`:  "•"

#### Dash

- The dash: "-"
- The en-dash (`&ndash;`): "–"
- The em-dash (`&mdash;`): "—"

Are there others?

Thank you for reading.

Brian

Comment: numbers / wicked multibyte symbols / images were first popping into my mind, wikipedia mentions "." and "o" for "ASCII-only text"

Comment: • is also memorable as &bull;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashes have a Unicode category of `Pd`.  As of Unicode 5.2, there are 21 of these characters:

- U+002D - HYPHEN-MINUS
- U+058A ֊ ARMENIAN HYPHEN
- U+05BE ־ HEBREW PUNCTUATION MAQAF
- U+1400 ᐀ CANADIAN SYLLABICS HYPHEN
- U+1806 ᠆ MONGOLIAN TODO SOFT HYPHEN
- U+2010 ‐ HYPHEN
- U+2011 ‑ NON-BREAKING HYPHEN
- U+2012 ‒ FIGURE DASH
- U+2013 – EN DASH
- U+2014 — EM DASH
- U+2015 ― HORIZONTAL BAR
- U+2E17 ⸗ DOUBLE OBLIQUE HYPHEN
- U+2E1A ⸚ HYPHEN WITH DIAERESIS
- U+301C 〜 WAVE DASH
- U+3030 〰 WAVY DASH
- U+30A0 ゠ KATAKANA-HIRAGANA DOUBLE HYPHEN
- U+FE31 ︱ PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL EM DASH
- U+FE32 ︲ PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL EN DASH
- U+FE58 ﹘ SMALL EM DASH
- U+FE63 ﹣ SMALL HYPHEN-MINUS
- U+FF0D － FULLWIDTH HYPHEN-MINUS

Bullets are a lot more complicated, as the others have mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

In unicode there are *lots*.  How about:

- Black left pointing index: U+261A ☚
- Black right pointing index: U+261B ☛
- White left pointing index: U+261C ☜
- White right pointing index: U+261E ☞

just for a quick example.  Heck, there is a whole *range* dedicated to various kinds of [arrows (2190–21FF)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2190.pdf), which can easily be used as bullet points.   I guess you can start to browse unicode [code pages](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) - there are a *lot* of characters out there, though.  I expect you'll have a hard time finding everything anybody might use.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen `+`, `>`, and `#` used to indicate bullet points.

Answer (score 1):

Even ordinary windows, code-page characters like: º+·˙̣·۰۠۟۟•▪■□►●○▬─
can be used -- Especially if CSS is used to size and position them.

.
Also, pretty much the same significance as a bullet point, but *ordered*, is outline notation:

```
1.
2.
2.1
2.1.A
2.1.B
etc.
```